# Error with Cisco Anyconnect VPN on Mojave

Tags: vpn

I am on *Mojave 10.14.3* and I am using *Cisco AnyConnect 4.6.00362*. When connecting to my VPN i get the following message

> Posture Assessment Failed: Unable to download CSD library. Please try again

Anyhelp on this is appreciated.

Comment: Same error but on Windows XP.